# Property [] does not exist on belongs to many pivot relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can't seem to be able to get my pivot relationships when using a belongs to many relationship! My structure looks like this

**user Model**

```
class Users extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function contacts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Contacts', 'user_contacts', 'user_id', 'contact_id');
    }

}
```

**contacts Model**

```
class Contacts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contacts';
}
```

**user_contacts Table**

```
id | user_id | contact_id
1  |       1 |        1
```

**users Table**

```
id | Name 
1  | Jim Bliggs
```

**contacts Table**

```
id | Name       | Telephone
1  | Joe Bloggs | 0 111 1111
```

I can save using the relationship fine like so

```
$user->contacts()->save($newContact);
```

But whenever I try to get all the contacts for a user to loop through them like this

```
$users = Users::all();
dd($users->contacts);
```

It just returns

> Property [Contacts] does not exist on this collection instance.

Sorry if its a simple question, but I cant understand how I can create using the relationship but i cant read?

Comment: What happens if you add `()` to those `$users->contacts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$users = Users::all();
```

would return a collection of Users, You need to loop through the users, to get its associated contacts

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    dump($user->contacts);
}
```

To alleviate the N + 1 query problem, you could [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the User's contacts

```
$users = User::with('contacts')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    dump($user->contacts);
}
```

Comment: If you happened to be someone who downvoted me for this answer, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You should define the inverse on Contact model:

```
class Contacts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contacts';

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Users', 'user_contacts', 'contact_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And to access a users contacts you need to loop the collection:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // $user->contacts
}

// using higher order proxy
$users->each->contacts
```

Comment: Please could you explain why should I define the inverse Contact model? Is it just for good practise? If i'm only ever going to be accessing Contacts via the users model, does it still need to be defined?

Comment: I consider it good practice, however, if you're never accessing users via contacts then you wouldn't need it.